# Nginx SSL slow initial connection time

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, tls1.2

Issue:
[image]

This is definitely not normal. The initial connection time is crazy. I suppose it's an handshake problem.

Tried to play around with protocols and ciphers.
Nothing.

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /home/ec2-user/ssl/bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ec2-user/ssl/keyhere;
       # keepalive_timeout 70;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
      #  ssl_ciphers aNULL:eNULL:MD5:LOW:HIGH;
      #  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
       ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;

        location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/dist;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

**The http loads in 2/3 sec.**

the server ssl protocol/cipher

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

I am open to suggestions :)

Comment: The time shown is about the __TCP__ connection. The SSL handshake is shown in the next item and it is normal. So it is not a SSL handshake problem. TCP connection is done by the OS kernel so the nginx configuration is likely not the problem. Check if something is inferring with the traffic, like a firewall.

Comment: Steffen thanks for your answer. Good point, but then why http is so fast?

Comment: Same IP but different port - who knows what happens in between. Again, check for firewalls etc on the way. The best way to debug such problems is to eliminate as much factors as possible first and then slowly add these. That is: try near the server (like on same machine or directly connected). Also do a packet capture on the server and compare with what you see at the client (i.e. looking for dropped packets)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the similar issue, the initial connection time took also around 21s.
Only after using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html I found that one of the IP addresses that where connected with the domain name had no service in Kubernetes running behind.
And so when I hit the url of my app in a browser it first probably went looking into that IP address that had no service running.

The app was served by Nginx.

I also used https://www.webpagetest.org/ for testing the loading speed.

Comment: This was beyond helpful.

Comment: 3.2 ms.. Thanlks a lot..